# Persistent terminal in indicator panel

Tags: command-line, indicator

I'm looking for a plugin / applet that will run a persistent tiny terminal (even just one line) in the indicator panel (or below it, or at the bottom of my screen - somewhere out of the way) on Ubuntu 14+

I remember older versions of Ubuntu had these little applets, such as temperature, CPU usage etc. I have looked at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top) thread. I have also seen other distros of Linux where a persistent terminal (a few lines high) runs at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Guake Terminal from software center. Its a drop down terminal and add it in your start up programs.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Tilda which is like Guake. I just want something to persist rather than toggling using a key stroke